# C++ copy constructor is not invoking (compilation error)

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation, copy

This code doesn't compile (please ignore passing by value in operator+, I could replace it by reference & but it still doesn't solve the issue)
I expect in main function:

```
String s3 = s + s2; // COMPILATION ERROR
```

to be compiled ok (because I declare copy constructor) but it gives error ("no matching constructor")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class String {
public:
    String()
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor " << this << std::endl;
        data = new char[100];
    };

    String(char * str) : String()
    {
        std::cout << "Char * Constructor " << this << std::endl;
        strcpy(this->data,str);
    };

    String(String & rhs) : String() {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl;
        strcpy(data, rhs.data);

    };


    void print() {
        printf("%s\n",data);
    }

    ~String() {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << this << std::endl;

        if (data) {
            delete data;
            data = nullptr;
        }
    };
    friend String operator+(String s1, String s2);

private:
    char * data;
};

String operator+(String s1, String s2)
{
    String temp;
    delete [] temp.data;
    temp.data =
    new char[strlen(s1.data) + strlen(s2.data) + 1];
    strcpy(temp.data, s1.data);
    strcat(temp.data, s2.data);
    return temp;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    String s("herer");
    s.print();
    String s2 = s;
    s2.print();
    String s3 = s + s2; // COMPILATION ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if your input string contains more than 100 characters? Pass the strings to your operators by const reference to avoid copies. Do NOT delete the internal data outside of a string object, as in your operators. That defeats the point of C++

Comment: good point. how its better to organize code to not access the internal data in external ( friend ) operator+ then?

Comment: String constructor should find out the size of the input string and allocate the correct amount of memory. You should also implement an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors with your code.  First

```
String(char * str)
```

Needs to be

```
String(const char * str)
```

If you want to use string literals like you do in `main()` with `String s("herer");`.  Secondly Your copy constructor

```
String(String & rhs)
```

Needs to take be

```
String(const String & rhs)
```

So that it can bind to temporaries.

Third you need to include `<cstring>` or `<string.h>` in order to use `strcpy()`.

Lastly you are using the wrong `delete` in you destructor.  When you call `new` you use `delete` and when you use `new[]` you call `delete []`.  You use `new[]` to allocate `data` but you are deleting it with `delete`.

You can see a working example of your code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b4f79b1e304d1c5)

Comment: thanks for detailed code review. Now its much more clear. so the compiler doesn't allow non const arguments to bind to temporary objects. Btw why does it allowed me to use this non-const copy constructor in operator+ then ? (I mean even if I use reference & form of it)

Comment: A reference cannot bind to an rvalue which is what the result of `s + s2` is.  A reference can only bind to an lvalue which gets it name as it can be on the left hand side of an `=` sign.  that is why you can copy them in `operator +()` but you couldn't copy it's result because the returned string is not an lvalue.

Comment: oh, now I see. it does make sense. if I use lvalue objects with "adress" the compiler uses non-const reference form of copy constructor. but temporary (s+s2) expression is the rvalue so compiler cannot bind to it with non const reference! (I can only assume that its due to rvalue result will be wasted anyway so no need to make it mutable thats why compilre explicitly requires const-ness there) thanks a lot. it is insightful :)

Comment: @barney if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: more to say. unfortunately, the compiler is not intelligent enough to point to this type casting issue in more explicit manner. I had to have some external knowledge to understand the issue. just wander is there any advanced compilers or static analyzers for c++ that could show the problem instantly?

Comment: @barney I am not sure what compiler you are using but any modern compiler should give you a decent error message.  g++ will give you the following error if you have `String&` vs `const String&`: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'String&' from an rvalue of type 'String'`

Answer (score 0):

The argument of the copy constructor must be `const&`.

```
String(String const & rhs) : String() { ... }
```